# sudo apt-get install got Unmet dependencies result

Tags: apt

I have this error on `Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-198-generic #230-Ubuntu SMP Sat Nov 28 01:30:29 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-6 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 g++-6 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 g++-6-multilib : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 gcc-6 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 gcc-6-multilib : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 lib32asan3 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 lib32cilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 lib32gcc-6-dev : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 lib32stdc++-6-dev : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 lib32ubsan0 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libasan3 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.23-0ubuntu11.2) but 2.23-0ubuntu3 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.23-0ubuntu3) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.2 is installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgcc-6-dev : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
            Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgcc1 : Breaks: libgcc1:i386 (!= 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1) but 1:9.3.0-10ubuntu2~12.04 is installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc1 (!= 1:9.3.0-10ubuntu2~12.04) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libstdc++-6-dev : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) but 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~12.04 is installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~12.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is installed
 libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04) but 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I try to update:

```
$ sudo apt-get install updata
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package updata
```

```
$ sudo apt update
     Hit:1 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze InRelease [7,126 B]
Err:4 http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1530185191
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple     times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt/dists/squeeze/InRelease: Signature by key E570B40867757573C52F115D062C7EBC11FFD694 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1530185191
E: The repository 'http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:47 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
```

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys E570B40867757573C52F115D062C7EBC11FFD694
Executing: /tmp/tmp.NXrgNdYHtv/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
pool.sks-keyservers.net
--recv-keys
E570B40867757573C52F115D062C7EBC11FFD694
gpg: requesting key 11FFD694 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key 11FFD694: "Charles du Jeu (AjaXplorer Team) <charles@ajaxplorer.info>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What OS & release are you on?   You messages show lots of ESM/EOL requirements, from releases that are now off-topic here, and whilst you've told us your kernel; that's used by both an on-topic (but very soon to be off-topic release) and multiple off-topic (EOL/ESM) releases, so please clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel) and [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760896/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems at play:

1)

```
Err:4 http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1530185191
```

For that, see for example [GPG KEYEXPIRED error in when updating repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823616/gpg-keyexpired-error-in-when-updating-repositories/823621#823621)

If you can't get the current public key for this repository with `apt-key`, you need to look into where your setup expects the key to be. Using `apt-key` is phased out currently in favor of storing individual keys in the file system.

Look for the `deb` entry that corresponds to this repository somewhere in `/etc/apt`. If this `deb` entry has something like `[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg]` in it, you need to refresh the file mentioned there with the current key. There's probably a note how to download the key in the repository's description.

2)

It's `update`, not `updata` ;) Also, there's no package named `update` (or `updata`), so you can't install it. This is what your system tells you in `E: Unable to locate package updata`. You may want to look into the systematics of `apt` again, so you won't go to basically nonsensical (no offense) things like `sudo apt-get install updata` again.

3)

You seem to have configured some repositories that offer *some* packages you need, but not *all* of them. For example, when you try to install `cpp-6`, it additionally needs `gcc-6-base`. For the version of `cpp-6` you *do* have available, you would need `gcc-6-base 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~12.04`, but you've only got `gcc-6-base 6.0.1-0ubuntu1`.

4)

As guiverc already mentioned in his comment to your question, you seem to use at least *some* quite old software. As you can see, the `gcc-6-base` package you would like to install (if you had it) is for Ubuntu 12.04, so from 2012.

Overall, you might want to do a throrough spring cleaning of your machine. Maybe it would help to ask somebody to look at in person, perhaps from your local Linux User Group if available. Ultimately, it might even be easier to backup all data you want to keep and do fresh install. But that's not easy to decide remotely.